# Configuration of Maven profile to connect with SonarQube which is using LDAP

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin

How to configure Maven profile (inside the settings.xml file) to create a report in SonarQube which uses LDAP to authenticate users.
I would like to perform a Maven command from my local machine:

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar -Psonar
```

How to fix the user and password for profile 'sonar' to pass the LDAP authentication in SonarQube?

```
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>http://some_url/sonar</sonar.host.url>
        <!--???---LDAP user configuration---???-->
        <sonar.scm.disabled>true</sonar.scm.disabled>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use user tokens instead of a login and a password. This is safer because you don't expose your password and because you can revoke the token at any point of time.

For that purpose:

1. Go to "My Account > Security" and generate a token on that page
2. Add the following property on your `settings.xml` file:

   `<sonar.login>123456abcdef</sonar.login>`

Comment: This could work, but I don't have Global Permission "Administer System" rights (BTW. I'm using version 5.1.0)